# Create a logStream for each log file in cloudwatchLogs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, configuration, stream, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I use `AWS CloudWatch` log agent to push my application log to AWS Cloudwatch.

In the `cloudwatchLogs` config file inside my `EC2 instance`, I have this entry:

```
[/scripts/application]
datetime_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
file = /workingdir/customer/logfiles/*.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = {instance_id}
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = /scripts/application
```

According to this configuration, all log files in workingdir directory are being sent to cloudwatchLogs in the same stream were the name is the instance Id.

My question is, **I want for each log file, create a separate `logStream`, so that the logs reading can be more fast and parseable**. In other words, **every time I have a new log file, a new logstream is created automatically.**

I thought of doing that by a shell script in a cron job but then I'll have to change many other configurations in the architecture, so I'm looking for a way to do it in the config file. In the documentation, they say that :

> log_stream_name
>
> Specifies the destination log stream. You can use a literal string or
>   predefined variables ({instance_id}, {hostname}, {ip_address}), or
>   combination of both to define a log stream name. A log stream is
>   created automatically if it doesn't already exist.

The names of the log files can't be 100% predictible, but they always have this structure though:

```
CustomerName-YYYY-mm-dd.log
```

Also, another problem is that :

> A running agent must be stopped and restarted for configuration
>   changes to take effect.

How can I set the logStream in this case?

Any ideas or suggestions or workarounds are very appreciated.

Comment: I know you asked this quite some time ago but did you find a solution in the end? I'm experiencing the same limitations in trying to configure the AWS logging agent to be more automated, avoiding the need to configure each log stream separately; we simply have too many log files for this to be feasible, so any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 2024 - the same limitation is still in place

Answer (score 5):

I know it's been almost two years now, but I wanted to do the exact same thing and couldn't find a way to get it to work.
I resorted to the AWS Support, which then confirmed this cannot be done. We're limited to the options offered in the documentation, just like you posted. You can, however, have **log groups** contain the log file path up to the first dot:

> log_group_name – Optional. Specifies what to use as the log group name
>   in CloudWatch Logs. Allowed characters include a-z, A-Z, 0-9, '_'
>   (underscore), '-' (hyphen), '/' (forward slash), and '.' (period).
>
> We recommend that you specify this field to prevent confusion. **If you
>   omit this field, the file path up to the final dot is used as the log
>   group name. For example, if the file path is
>   /tmp/TestLogFile.log.2017-07-11-14, the log group name is
>   /tmp/TestLogFile.log.**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html